# What is the overview of serialization in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Perhaps someone who has more experience with Spark can help with the following serialization related questions: :)

Would the following be an accurate description of one of the serialization paths that happen in Spark:

- `RDD --> Bytestream (Java/Kryo)`
- `Dataset --> Bytestream (Encoders)`

In this [talk](https://youtu.be/Ofk7G3GD9jk?t=1275) about `RDD`, `Dataframe` and `Dataset` in spark, it was stated that `RDD` is still the fundamental data structure at play in Spark, and hence even `Dataset`s builds on `RDD`

How should that statement be interpreted? Does it mean that the serialization path for a `Dataset` is:

`Dataset -->(encoders) RDD --> Bytestream(Java/kryo)`

Or does encoders also work in translating RDD's into Bytestream?

Comment: It's a huge topic. An easy overview is that RDD:s use plain java objects. The dataset API (and it's alias dataframe) use tungsten which in it's first incarnation used a proprietary binary row format, in it's 2nd generation is migrating to a vectorized columnar format. A short explanation https://spoddutur.github.io/spark-notes/deep_dive_into_storage_formats.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all neither `RDD` nor `Dataset` is not serialized as a whole. Correctly would be to say that in `RDD[T]` and `Dataset[T]` each element of type `T` is serialized.

The statement, that `Dataset` is built on `RDD`s means that `Dataset` is only an abstraction for convenience and optimization. And whenever a calculation on `Dataset` is triggered - the `Datasets` transformations are converted into the `RDD` transformations, after applying optimizations.

I cannot say for sure how exactly it works in spark - probably only developers who wrote that could answer that or someone who can spend some time digging into spark sources, but assumtion is that, if we have transformations of `Dataset[T]`:

1. Whenever data is stored anywhere - it is encoded using `Encoders`
2. Transformation graph is build on `RDD[Array[Byte]]`, because of 1.

`Dataset[T] --(encoders)--> RDD[Array[Byte]]`

Hope that helps!